# Do-while loop factorial. ( factorial *= x will eventually give a negative number)

Tags: java, do-while, factorial

I need to write a program that caldulates the factorial of a number given by the user that must satisfy certain conditions. This must be done using non-nested do-while loop
I have managed to validate the input. And it even calculates the correct factorials for int up to 12.
When the input is 13, it outputs the wrong answer.

This is what i've got:

```
    int factorial = 1; 
    int x = 1;
    int i = 0;
    do {
        if ( i > 0) { 
            factorial *= x;
            x--;
            //I added this line to see what was going on and found that at
            //some point it would output a negative value
            System.out.println(factorial + " x " + x);
            continue;
        }

        if (myScanner.hasNextInt()) {

            x = myScanner.nextInt();
            i = 1;

            if (x < 9 || x > 16) {

               System.out.println("Invalid input, enter again:"); 

               x = 1;
               i = 0;
            }
        } 

        else {

            String invalid  = myScanner.nextLine(); 

            System.out.println("Invalid input, enter again:");
        }

    }
    while (x > 0);

    System.out.println("Answer is: " + factorial);
}//end main method
```

When I enter 13 this is what I get:

```
Please enter an integer that is between 9 and 16:
13
13 x 12
156 x 11
1716 x 10
17160 x 9
154440 x 8
1235520 x 7
8648640 x 6
51891840 x 5
259459200 x 4
1037836800 x 3 
//Everything works fine until here. Why? How can I fix it?
-1181456896 x 2 
1932053504 x 1
1932053504 x 0
Answer is: 1932053504
```

Comment: [Integer Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Comment: The Java `int` type goes up to `2^31-1` and then overflows. Use `long` instead and you will get a bit more range to play with.